# only chromium's border is visible while running test in playwright

Tags: playwright, wsl-2

I am using playwright to right test for our website. In playwright.config.ts I have configured to chromium browser with headless set to false. Earlier everything was working file but now while running the test the browser open but it is transparent and only border is visible. The output screenshot is also doesn't contain anything.
[image]

I am using ubuntu through wsl2 of windows 11.
The followings are still working fine with playwright:

- chromium browser with headless set to true
- firefox browser with either headless set to true or false

also chromium browser installed by playwright at location /xxx/xxxx/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1028/chrome-linux/chrome is working fine

my playwright config file is

```
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

// Read from default ".env" file.
dotenv.config();

// Alternatively, read from "../my.env" file.
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve('./my.env') });

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        // channel: 'chrome',
        headless: false
    },
    webServer: {
        command: ' ~/.yarn/bin/netlify dev',
        port: 8888
    },
    testDir: './tests'
};

export default config;
```

Comment: No. It is still not working on my computer.